# replacing a pointer with another pointer with different size

Tags: c++, pointers, memory-management, dynamic-memory-allocation

It seems that this code could work in c++. But I still don't understand why. Since the old array and newArray have different sizes, why it's fine to let the old array equal the new array.

```
int* oldArray = new int[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        oldArray[i] = i;
    }

    int* newArray = new int[10];
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        newArray[i] = i * i;
    }

    delete[] oldArray;
    oldArray = newArray;
    
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        std::cout << oldArray[i] << std::endl;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

The `oldArray` is just a pointer to a memory location where the array is
stored. It has no information about the size it points to as it is basically just a starting address of the array.

Being a pointer you can set it to point to another address in memory, in this case the same place `newArray` is pointing.

```
             +---+---+---+---+---+
oldArray --> | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 
             +---+---+---+---+---+

             +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
newArray --> | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
             +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+

oldArray = newArray

oldArray 
         \
          \  +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
          /  | 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 |
         /   +---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+---+
newArray
```